# Creating a 3-column layout on a Wordpress Page

Tags: pages, columns

At the moment I am creating a page with Wordpress. Now there is some content, that won't chance often, that's why I want to use a page for it. I also want to create a custom template for that page. You see, nothing special.
On that page, I want a 3-column layout, meaning 3 different blocks of text positioned with normal HTML. Now the problem is, when I use a normal page in Wordpress, there is only one text area in the admin area which basically means that I can't have 3 different blocks of texts accessible through the admin area. How do I realize this without hardcoding the text into the HTML? Of course I could write it as a plugin, but that seems a bit over the top for me.
I hope you understand my problem, it's hard to explain for me, I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for this. You can use it to add other entry fields to a post type (in this case, you'd probably want to add it to the Page type). In your case, you would probably want two other [Wysiwyg Editor fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/wysiwyg-editor/) so you can write with formatting.

The trick will be that, if you assign the new fields to the Page post type, **all** pages will have the two extra fields. You may want to [create a new post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and assign the fields to that.

Another way to go about this would be using something like the [Chunks plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/chunks/). This allows you to have small snippets of content that you can call into a theme whenever you'd like. Using this would allow you to have saved pieces of text you could use in one of the columns, and also include that text elsewhere on the site, if you'd like.

Also, one further idea: if you just want the content to flow into three columns and it's mostly going to be text, you could use [CSS3's `column-count`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). This doesn't work in all browsers by default, but there are [cross-browser shims like css3-multi-column.js](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) which can fix that for you.

Comment: Great, it worked using the two plugins in combination following your tips. The column-count option also worked, but the plugin-combo was more suitable for my project.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear I could help. I hope the rest of your project goes well! :)